# vba: select table from row 3 to end for listobject

Tags: excel, vba

Selecting a whole sheet for a listobject is done this way

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Cost"
```

But now I want the same but starting with row number 3:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim crng As Range
Set crng = ws.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A3"), ws.Range(crng.Columns, crng.Rows))

ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "Eval"
```

But this also selects the whole range.
How can I choose the correct range?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row.

Comment: The *hacky* way would be to use `ws.Cells(crng.Rows.Count, crng.Columns.Count)`, but highly suggest you don't do that.

Comment: Are you trying to select from Excel row 3 or the 3rd in the listobject? also if 3rd row counting the header or just the body?

Comment: Is it not possible to get the last row  and column from currentregion?

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended. If your data has no gaps and starts in A1, then try the `ws.Cells` approach instead of `ws.Range`.

Comment: Ok. I know my rows and column count from my variables. so this works for me:
`Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A3"), ws.Cells(UBound(data), 10))`

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases - when a table exists in range "A3" or when there is no table there.

- **When a table exists**

I have managed to select from `A3` to the end of the table with the code below:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    Dim myRange As Range

    With ws
        Set myRange = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("A3").End(xlToRight))
        Set myRange = .Range(myRange, myRange.End(xlDown))
    End With

    myRange.Select
    Stop
    'Uncomment the line below, if there is no table.
    'ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, myRange, , xlYes).Name = "Eval40"
End Sub
```

However, if you uncomment the last line of the code, you will see the `1004` error, which states something like "A table cannot over lap another table", which makes sense, as the new table, named `Eval40` is part of the old table which already exists.

- **When a table does not exist**
  If there is no existing table at the range, then it works ok:

[image]

Comment: This solution uses `xlToRight`. in my comment I had used variables. If you add my solution to our answer I can check it.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech - I am afk, feel free to edit the `xlToRight`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign the range just using `row(3)`

```
Set rng = ws.Rows(3)
```

Comment: OP wants all the data, not just row 3.

Comment: this gives me a table with the complete row (up to the end), and inserts a second row (at 4) which is empty. I want the used region but only from row 3 to the end.

Comment: Ah okay, my bad I misunderstood the question. Thanks for clarifying.